# os.path.exists returns incorrect result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I first encountered this problem, it happened by chance and funny.

os.path.exists doesn't determine the wrong path if there is a space at the end of the path. (**Windows**)

```py
os.path.exists('C:\Python37 ')  # true
```

or here is another example:

```py
def get_files_from_folder(path):
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(path) and os.path.exists(path):
            return os.listdir(path)
        else:
            return []
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "Error: the path doesn't exist"

print(get_files_from_folder('C:\Python37'))
# ['DLLs', 'Doc' ...]

print(get_files_from_folder('C:\Python37 '))
# Error: the path doesn't exist
```

It is logical that in the second case the function should have returned an empty list since the second conditions is false in if state... But it does not happen.

What's wrong? Why is this happening?

I have only one way to verify such a case.

```py
try:
    if os.path.isdir(path) and os.path.exists(path) \
            and type(os.listdir(path)) is list:
        ...
except FileNotFoundError:
    ...
```

But it's so ugly.

p.s. python 3.7

edit:
@MrFuppes correctly noted that spaces cannot be at the end of a folder name

possible solution:

```py
import platform

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    path=path.rstrip()
```

It's a little better than type comparing.

Comment: That happens because python throws an Exception. It never goes to our else statement. If you want to return an empty list use another try except in your try

Comment: `os.path.exists('C:\Python37 ')  # true` - no, it's not `True`. Have you actually tried to execute this exact line in the interpreter?

Comment: @ForceBru: also `True` for me, can reproduce it...

Comment: @ForceBru
Yeap I tried.

```
C:\Users\username>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists('C:\Python37 ')
True
>>>
```

Comment: Me too, just encountered same behaviour. But only when it is a directory. On actual files it returms `False`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe that's because I'm on Linux...

Comment: my guess would be that it just doesn't matter as you can't create a path (folder) with spaces trailing the folder name, right?

Comment: Anyway, @YeapyBen the output you are getting is because `listdir` is raising the exception, not `exists`... change `return os.listdir(path)` to `return True` for example and you will see both will be `True`

Comment: @MrFuppes

Yeap it is. Do I need to check the tail of the path?

Comment: you could use something like `return os.listdir(path.strip())` as a quick hack if your paths are represented as strings - things get more complicated if you also use `Path` objects from the `pathlib` module.

Comment: @MrFuppes
Сan I insert spaces at the end and beginning of a folder name in Unix? 
No way to check it now.

Comment: No way too... I am also on Win. ForceBru was saying he is on Linux

Comment: @ForceBru, you are right, this is a Windows thing, just checked on my Linux machine and it gave me a `False` if I appended a space to the end of the path... Also on Linux, you can have spaces before and after a folder name, which is not possible on Windows.

Comment: @Tomerikoo
```python
os.listdir(path)``` throws an exception if the path does not exist.

Comment: @YeapyBen, yes you can do that on Linux, so be careful with the `strip()` hack if you also want to used on non-Windows machines...

Comment: @MrFuppes Okey, thanks.

Comment: @YeapyBen, I like your solution using `platform`. I think you should note at the beginning of the question that you're on Windows. Imho, this is more of a Linux vs. Windows thing, since Python actually behaves logical in a sense: on Windows, leading/trailing spaces do not occur since not allowed by the operating system. So Python doesn't care. On Linux, the spaces are possible, so Python cares. Btw. also applies e.g. for `os.mkdir` [link](https://bugs.python.org/issue22744).

Comment: @MrFuppes also
```pathlib.Path('C:\Python37 ').exists()  # True
```

Comment: Sidenote: on Windows, you can well have spaces at the beginning of the foldername, just not at the end. Sorry for the confusion. Try `os.mkdir('D:\     test')` and then try to rename the folder in Windows Explorer... just weird.

Comment: @MrFuppes, yeap, thanks. Change ```strip()``` to ```rstrip()```

Comment: @MrFuppes

after adding another space to the beginning, it gives an error in the OS, considers these to be the same names. It's funny